# Complete example of wxwidgets custom event passing string data

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I am receiving messages from the network on a non-GUI thread and need to use [wxEvtHandler::AddPendingEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandleraddpendingevent) to tell the GUI to update accordingly. I also need to pass data to my GUI code so that it can act apropriately.

I believe I have to create a custom event, but haven't found a straightforward implementation. This closest thing that I've found is The wxWiki on [Creating a Custom Event](http://wiki.wxwindows.org/Custom_Events#Creating_a_Custom_Event_-_Method_4), which is a partial example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are receiving messages from a different thread, then [you explicitily can not use AddPendingEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#0737c6d2cbcd5ded4b1ecdd53ed0def3).  You must instead use [wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#cffd03bf407a856166ea71ef0318b59a).

Second, there are a couple of good examples for creating custom event classes: [the old way](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_eventhandlingoverview.html#eventhandlingoverview), [the new way](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_custom).

With the old way, you can also use the Connect method and leave off the event table, but it's not illustrated in that example.  The new way has the much preferred Bind method... but as you can see in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037525/wxwidgets-2-9-custom-events), I'm having my own problems with it.